# Check if a string evaluates to the name of a variable in zsh - Indirect expansion

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm trying to check if a string evaluates to a name of a variable. This works in bash:

```
[[ -z "${!VALUE_OF_VAR}" ]]
```

But in ZShell it results in an invalid substitution. What's the equivalent in ZShell to check if a variable evaluates to the name of a variable (is set)?

Comment: Cross-site dupe from Unix.SE - [${!FOO} and zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68035)

Comment: That returns true both if `VALUE_OF_VAR` contains a name that is not a variable *and* if it contains the name of a variable whose value is the empty string.

Comment: @Inian Consider undeleting your answer as it is a better answer to the question than the current one.

Comment: @user3589502 Do you think you could Accept my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike `bash`, indirect expansion is dealt in a different way in `zsh` which can be found in the [zsh - official documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) under Parameter expansion flags

```
P
```

> This forces the value of the parameter name to be interpreted as a further parameter name, whose value will be used where appropriate. Note that flags set with one of the typeset family of commands (in particular case transformations) are not applied to the value of name used in this fashion.

> If used with a nested parameter or command substitution, the result of that will be taken as a parameter name in the same way. For example, if you have `foo=bar` and `bar=baz`, the strings `${(P)foo}`, `${(P)${foo}}`, and `${(P)$(echo bar)}` will be expanded to `baz`.

Adopting on of the formats above, I think you need

```
[[ -z "${(P)VALUE_OF_VAR}" ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check whether `$varname` evaluates to the name of a declared variable, you can simply use `[[ -v $varname ]]`.

For example:

```
% varname=var
% var=
% [[ -v $varname ]]; print $?
0
% unset var
% [[ -v $varname ]]; print $?
1
```